# Keyboard package doesn't work with sudo command launch

Tags: python, linux, keyboard, python-import, sudo

When I try to launch the program from terminal (Linux) with:

```
$ python script.py
```

it works fine.
But when I need to add the root privileges (sudo):

```
$ sudo python script.py
```

I obtain the message:

> ImportError: No module named keyboard

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that pip installed the package in destination in .~local/lib/python2.7/site-packages instead of /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.

Comment: How did you manage to get pip to install the package in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages?

Comment: @BernardEsterhuyse per my experience, `sudo pip install <package_name>` installs packages to system location (like /something/something) and `pip install --user <package_name>` (without sudo) installs to user locations like (~/.local/...)